# BigQuery Standard SQL - Join on date with different formats

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'd like to perform a join between two tables using the date column.
However, since they come from two different dataset, the tables use two different formats:

```
Table_1 -> date: 2020-04-23 17:00:00 UTC
Table 2 -> date: 2020-04-11
```

Is there a way to do this in BigQuery in standard SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date columns do not have different formats.  `date` is a built-in data type.  But there are three types for storing date/times:  `date`, `datetime`, and `timestamp`.

You can convert `datetime` and `timestamp`s to dates.  That allows you to do:

```
from table_1 t1 join
     table_2 t2
     on date(t2.timestamp) = t1.date
```

You may want to include a timezone specified in the logic as well, but your question does not reference this.  It assumes the days are UTC as well.